# Como gerar um ID dinâmico para minha Button com PHP e passar para o JS?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sweetalert

Estou tentando usar o PHP com o Sweet Alert já tentei com ID FIXA e funciona.
Estou tentando isso:

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td>' . $row['id_apoio'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $row['nome_apoio'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $row['email_apoio'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $row['tel_apoio'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $row['cel_apoio'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $row['cargo_apoio'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $row['especialidade_apoio'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $row['conselho_apoio'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td><button class="bg-transparent border-0 d-block mx-auto" onclick="location.href=\'cadastro-completo-apoio.php?cadastro='. $row['id_apoio'] .'\'"><i class="fa fa-search"></i><br></td>';
                            echo '<td><button class="bg-transparent border-0 d-block mx-auto" onclick="location.href=\'editar-apoio.php?edita='. $row['id_apoio'] .'\'"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i><br></td>';
                            echo '<td><button class="bg-transparent border-0 d-block mx-auto sweet-alert" id="'.$row['id_apoio'].'"><i class="fa fa-user-times"></i><br></button>';
                        }
                        ?>
```

JS:

```
    document.getElementById('<?php $row['id_apoio']?>').onclick = function(){
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
            type: "info",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonClass: 'btn-primary',
            confirmButtonText: 'Primary!'
        });
    };
```

o botão servirá para confirmar a exclusão do item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa usar id pra pegar o click. Basta pegar por uma classe no botão. Acrescente mais uma classe no botão, algo como `deletar`, ficando assim as classes:

```
class="bg-transparent border-0 d-block mx-auto sweet-alert deletar"
```

Então você irá criar eventos de click para cada botão pela classe `.deletar` e usar o promise `.then` do Sweetalert para redirecionar a página pegando o id do botão quer disparou o evento caso você confirme:

```
const del_buts = document.getElementsByClassName("deletar");
for(let b of del_buts){
   b.onclick = function(){
      let id = this.id;
      swal({
         title: "Are you sure?",
         text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
         type: "info",
         showCancelButton: true,
         confirmButtonClass: 'btn-primary',
         confirmButtonText: 'Primary!'
      }).then(function(e){
        if(e){
           location.href='deleta-apoio.php?deleta='+id;
        }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez, Sam! vc é fera!

Comment: de qualquer forma, não consigo passar a id do usário para fazer o delete.

Comment: ```echo '<td><button class="bg-transparent border-0 d-block mx-auto deletar" onclick="location.href=\'deleta-apoio.php?deleta='. $row['id_apoio'] .'\'">```

o js é o que vc me passou...

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. Mantenha o id em cada button: `id="'.$row['id_apoio'].'` e retire esse onclick que vc colocou.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo e consegui entender como funciona essa integração. Se pudesse te dava um abraço. Sam is a beast